# WSP Solution File deployed using the Visual Studio - Debugging

Tags: sharepoint-addin, solution-package, deploy

We are trying to debug the Sharepoint wsp file deployed using the Powershell Command Install -sp Solution , but we are not able to attach the worker process (w3wp.exe) to the code running on the Internet Explorer browser as with the case when deployed using the Visual Studio deploy option.

Any Suggestions , are highly welcome.

Regards
Arvind

Comment: Did you create the wsp using Debug configuration in Visual Studio?

Comment: The WSP was created using the package option in Visual Studio and the debug option was selected in the server.

Comment: If you are deploying the solution using PowerShell, try attaching to this process as well

Comment: Already tried attaching to the w3wp.exe process, if any other process please let us know of the same.

Comment: Typically there's 3-4 w3wp processes running - make sure you show processes for all users and attach to them all. Try placing a breakpoint and see if it thinks the symbols have been loaded or not - you might want to rebuild and redeploy.

Comment: Even after attaching to all the worker process the symbols are not getting loaded and the breakpoint displays the symbol with exclamation. For the remaining methods of deploying (Publishing the code from Visual Studio) we are able to debug but when deployed through wsp's (from the Sharepoint Powershell) only we are facing the issue.